# Modify sound indicator menu to hide controls from inactive player or remove it after closeing

Tags: rhythmbox, indicator-sound, menu-bar

I like Spotify's indicator menu which expands whenever the application is open. I don't like Rhythmbox's which shows all the buttons all the time.

I'd like to hide the Rew/Play/FF buttons from Rhythmbox when the application is inactive.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Bug #1213907](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sound/+bug/1213907)

Comment: Just to be clear.  The solution is not something that I can easily tweak, but rather a bug that's been reported.  So I'd be better off ignoring it than trying to fix it...

Comment: No, the bug @edwin posted is a different issue I think. Nevertheless, this is probably not something we can help with but that you would have to hack rhythmbox's code to fix.

Comment: That's good to know. Cheerios.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Why was this closed? This ***is about Ubuntu***. It's about modifying the inbuilt sound/music application menu applet (`indicator-sound`). I would really want to see this reopened.

Comment: @ArkaMajumdar You are correct friend. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado No problem. Thanks for reopening it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sound indicator, with no active player (launchers only, no control buttons)**

[image: Sound indicator, with no active player (launchers only, no control buttons)]

**Sound indicator, with active player (full control buttons)**

[image: Sound indicator, with active player (full control buttons)]

---

## 15.10

Have same build steps as 14.04.

- **Remove player from menu after close**

  Modify `src/service.vala` for `desktop` menu to HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS.

  ```
  this.menus.insert ("desktop", new SoundMenu ("indicator.desktop-settings", SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.SHOW_MUTE|SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS));
  ```

  And modify `src/sound-menu.vala` for add_player function to remove_player_section if it is not running & hide inactive is set.

  ```
  public void add_player (MediaPlayer player) {
      if (this.notify_handlers.contains (player))
          return;

      if (player.is_running || !this.hide_inactive)
              this.insert_player_section (player);
          else         
              this.remove_player_section (player);
      this.update_playlists (player);
  ```
- **Hide player controls (Prev/Play/Next) from menu after close, keep only its launcher**

  Same as 14.04, no change.

---

## 14.04

1. Download build dependencies and source

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-sound
   apt-get source indicator-sound
   ```
2. Choose the behavior you want:

   - **Remove player from menu after close**

     Modify `src/service.vala` for `desktop` menu.

     ```
     this.menus.insert ("desktop", new SoundMenu ("indicator.desktop-settings", SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.SHOW_MUTE | SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS));
     ```

     I added `| SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS`, You can remove `SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.SHOW_MUTE |` if you want hide volume control with muted players.
   - **Hide player controls (Prev/Play/Next) from menu after close, keep only its launcher**

     Modify `src/sound-menu.vala`

     1. Add new flag `HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS_CONTROLS = 128` with `,` in end of previous line.

        ```
        public enum DisplayFlags {
            NONE = 0,
            SHOW_MUTE = 1,
            HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS = 2,
            HIDE_PLAYERS = 4,
            HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS_CONTROLS = 128
        }
        ```
     2. Add `bool hide_inactive_controls;` variable to hold flag status

        ```
        bool hide_inactive;
        bool hide_inactive_controls;
        bool hide_players = false;
        ```
     3. Add `this.hide_inactive_controls =...` line. to pass SoundMenu constructor flag parameter to its variable.

        ```
        this.hide_inactive = (flags & DisplayFlags.HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS) != 0;
        this.hide_inactive_controls = (flags & DisplayFlags.HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS_CONTROLS) != 0;
        this.notify_handlers = new HashTable<MediaPlayer, ulong> (direct_hash, direct_equal);
        ```
     4. Add `if (player.is_running || !this.hide_inactive_controls) {` and `}`. to wrap instructions which create (prev/play/next) in menu item. So they are not created only if player is running or hide flag is inactive.

        ```
        if (player.is_running || !this.hide_inactive_controls) {
            var playback_item = new MenuItem (null, null);
            playback_item.set_attribute ("x-canonical-type", "s", "com.canonical.unity.playback-item");
            playback_item.set_attribute ("x-canonical-play-action", "s", "indicator.play." + player.id);
            playback_item.set_attribute ("x-canonical-next-action", "s", "indicator.next." + player.id);
            playback_item.set_attribute ("x-canonical-previous-action", "s", "indicator.previous." + player.id);
            section.append_item (playback_item);
        }
        ```
     5. Add `if (this.hide_inactive_controls) {` to next `}`. To force player menu section recreation when player `is-running` state changes.

        ```
        var handler_id = player.notify["is-running"].connect ( () => {
            if (this.hide_inactive) {
                if (player.is_running) {
                    this.insert_player_section (player);
                }
                else {
                    this.remove_player_section (player);
                }
            }
            if (this.hide_inactive_controls) {
                this.remove_player_section (player);
                this.insert_player_section (player);
            }
            this.update_playlists (player);
        });
        ```
     6. Finally, modify `src/service.vala`. Add our new created flag `| SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS_CONTROLS` to `desktop` menu.

        ```
        this.menus.insert ("desktop", new SoundMenu ("indicator.desktop-settings", SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.SHOW_MUTE | SoundMenu.DisplayFlags.HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS_CONTROLS));
        ```
3. Build and install

   ```
   cd indicator-sound-12.10.2+14.04.20140313/
   mkdir build
   cd build/
   cmake ..
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Now, the players will disappear after closing them.

---

## 12.04

1. Download build dependencies and source

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-sound
   apt-get source indicator-sound
   ```
2. Modify `src/player-controller.vala`, Replace `"rhythmbox.desktop"` with `"xrhythmbox.desktop"` in the two occurrences. (just different name)
3. Build and install

   ```
   cd indicator-sound-0.8.5.0/
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```

**Note:** That was a quick trick, the correct way may be:

- Replace

  ```
    this.custom_items[widget_order.TRANSPORT].property_set_bool (MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE,
                                                            this.app_info.get_id() == "rhythmbox.desktop");
  ```

  with

  ```
    this.custom_items[widget_order.TRANSPORT].property_set_bool (MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE,
                                                            false);
  ```
- and

  ```
  if (this.app_info.get_id() == "rhythmbox.desktop"){
    TransportMenuitem transport = this.custom_items[widget_order.TRANSPORT] as TransportMenuitem;
    transport.handle_cached_action();
  }
  else{
    this.custom_items[widget_order.TRANSPORT].property_set_bool (MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE,
                                                             true);         
  }
  ```

  with

  ```
  this.custom_items[widget_order.TRANSPORT].property_set_bool (MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE,
                                                             true);
  ```

Comment: Thank you.  I have two problems with this instructions:    

I didn't have the file service.vala in src.  Am I suppose to create the file and include that line?   

Second, do I need to keep those folders in my home folder?  (Sorry, this is my first time modifying such source files)

Comment: This worked in 14.04, but it removed the applications completely from the menu.  Is it possible to only remove the Rew,Play,FF buttons but keep the startup buttons?

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  By the way, if you know of a reference to learn this kind of stuff, I could also welcome that.  =)

Comment: This is beautiful!!  I can get the code, but don't know what the objects or methods refer to.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on 15.10 anymore :(  The code for `indicator-sound` seems to be unchanged but when building it as you suggested it doesn't start up anymore

Comment: @wa4557 , updated for 15.10 . No major change so i suppose it will work for 14.10 & 15.04 too, enjoy!

Comment: @Sneetsher. Thanks! In your point 1. you're contradicting yourself. Is it  `HIDE_INACTIVE_PLAYERS_CONTROLS = 128`  or `=8`? (Because there is already `GREETER_PLAYERS = 8,`)

Comment: @wa4557,  ah I missed that, it is `128`  (8 & 16 have been used in 15.10, so I thought going to last for a byte. You may use 32 or 64 too) . Thank you, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @wa4557, no that was from 14.04 version, so add only lines I have added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32328/discussion-between-sneetsher-and-wa4557).