# Prevent VLC from always showing in the sound indicator

Tags: sound, indicator, vlc

VLC, a program I use only rarely, has an entry in the sound indicator. I can remove it using dconf by following instructions from [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-quickly-remove-media-players.html), but each time I start up VLC, despite it being in the "blacklisted-media-players" section, it reappears. I also tired some things listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12867/how-do-i-remove-players-i-dont-use-from-the-sound-indicator), but that didn't help either.

The entry "vlc.desktop" keeps appearing under "interested-media-players":
[image: "vlc.desktop" keeps appearing under "interested-media-players"]

Is it possible to either prevent VLC from showing up in the sound indicator menu entirely, or, preferably, only show up when I'm actively using it?

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40107/is-there-a-way-to-control-vlc-from-the-sound-menu

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it involves checking/unchecking a setting in VLC's preferences (D-Bus control interface) that no longer exists (I'm using 2.1.2 by the way).

Comment: see my edited answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/468839/72216 (further below)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove VLC player from sound menu in Unity bar](http://askubuntu.com/questions/468811/remove-vlc-player-from-sound-menu-in-unity-bar) or [Modify indicator menu for active/inactive applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435161/modify-indicator-menu-for-active-inactive-applications)

Comment: just to let you know, added another answer without the side effect Nick Bailuc mentioned http://askubuntu.com/a/484250/72216